# How can I create stories for generically typed Vue Components?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, typescript-generics, storybook

We're documenting the base components in our Vue project with [Storybook.js](https://storybook.js.org/). We're also striving to make everything, stories included, type-safe. We're also using the `satisfies` TS keyword to [ensure stricter type checks](https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-stories/typescript#using-satisfies-for-better-type-safety):

```js
const meta = {
  title: 'data-display/BaseGrid',
  component: BaseGrid,
  argTypes: {},
  args: {},
} satisfies Meta<typeof BaseGrid>;
```

And usually it works, but specifically for this component, it doesn't:

[image]

#### The cause

Tampering around a bit, I was able to narrow it down and found out it's due to the Vue component being [generically typed](https://dev.to/vincentdorian/vue-33-generic-types-and-when-to-use-them-5egn):

```html
<script lang="ts" setup generic="T extends GridRow">
// ... component implementation
</script>
```

The error goes away when I remove the `generic="T extends GridRow"` attribute, but the feature is important for this component, as it ensures emitted events and props all comply with the same contract - so we'd like to keep it there.

#### Workaround attempts

As I said earlier, we're trying our best to make the project type-safe, so that involves **avoiding `any` at all costs**. It seldom ends up in us resorting to fancy type gymnastics, but from my experience, it always paid off in the long run.

I tried to add the type arg in many places, but I keep getting lint errors:

- Tried asserting it as `typeof BaseGrid<SomeType>`;
- Tried using `satisfies Meta<typeof BaseGrid<SomeType>>`;
- Tried replacing `satisfies` with regular type annotation (e.g.: `meta<BaseGrid<SomeType>>>`);

And many other variations. I thought I might be trying to fix it in the wrong place, felt like I should be able to just pass the desired type arg somewhere, but maybe that's just lacking support for the feature in Storybook.js.

Can I work around this somehow or, better yet, is there an official way of declaring type args in generic Vue component stories?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's an [open issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/24238) in Storybook.js's GitHub.

While there still isn't an official way to do it, [Gumper-x's workaround](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/24238#issuecomment-1742004250) works:

```js
const meta = {
  title: 'MyComponent',
  component: MyComponent as unknown as Record<string, unknown>,
  // ...
} satisfies Meta<typeof MyComponent>;
```

However, it still looked a little bit too loosely typed for me. I was able to modify it and not only make it a little bit stricter but also drop the `unknown` conversion:

```js
const meta = {
  title: 'MyComponent',
  component: MyComponent as Record<keyof typeof MyComponent, unknown>,
  // ...
} satisfies Meta<typeof MyComponent>;
```